# Quasar Cordova Build "Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager"

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, quasar-framework, quasar

My own Quasar App failed to build for android platform, thats why i tried to build a clean app first, to eliminate my programming errors..
I tried building serveral Quasar/Cordova apps/examples for android platform after following a couple of instructions on how to setup cordova correctly...all of them keep failig like this...

```
  cordova build android --release
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Entwickler\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Entwickler\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\xampp\htdocs\quasar example\src-cordova\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\xampp\htdocs\quasar example\src-cordova\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b C:\xampp\htdocs\quasar example\src-cordova\platforms\android\build.gradle
```

I tried serveral gradle versions and even reinstalling all of it.
Steps to reproduce:

```
quasar create
quasar mode add cordova
cd src-cordova
cordova plattform add android
cd ..
quasar build -m cordova -T android
```

adding the --stacktracke option didnt help a lot.
Any help please :/ ?

Comment: i just avoided the problem by opening the folder with android studio and building it there .. not nite but it kinda works for the moment